# How do I achieve this realistic look?

Tags: hdri, effects

I am trying to copy [a video](https://youtu.be/SBkMEcBUaEs) with Blender.

I am using a HDRI world environment image but no post effects.

As one can see, my version still looks different:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what my scene is missing / how to achieve relatively exactely the same look?

When I watched the original video I didn't notice any effects, that is why I thought I could simply get away by just using an HDRI background image.

Do I still need a full lighting set?

Thank you!

Edit:

Here is my latest render according to the great changes by the answerer:

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a question of material, yours looks grey, not black enough, maybe share your file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### An HDRI is a good start.

But you'll need to place some lights manually to complete the look. Pay attention to the shadows in the reference: you'll notice that there seems to be a strong light from the upper-right.

[image: Shadow Differences]

Play around with adding and positioning lights. Try some Point Lights. It'll take some trial and error to get it close, but it's not impossible.

The only other difference I noticed was the color. I'm not an expert on color grading, but maybe try raising the contrast of your render a little bit in post?

### EDIT:

I looked at your file. Here's what I achieved after a few minutes of playing with lights:

[image: Test Render]

It's not exactly like the original, but it's closer. I added 4 point lights and positioned them according to the shadows in the original image. Take a look at the radius and brightness values.

Rather than change the color in compositing, I changed the actual color of the material (yes, it's too dark, but that should be easy to fix.) I also lowered the strength of the HDRI (it would probably work fine without it.)

Here's a simplified version of the file to demonstrate the new lighting.

[image]

Comment: Could I send you my file? I just don't get it... :-( :-(

Comment: Sure thing! If you could just upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post the link here, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's too big for blend-exchange. I have uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4kDNSC5rc2QJimG_J6-_7-0dgusCT7k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looking at your file now @tmighty.

Comment: @tmighty check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your version looks like! I have added the HDRI back in to the blend file that you provided. I have added the resulting render to my answer. My render unfortunately does not look like yours. Do you think you could perhaps upload the full version anywhere?

Comment: @tmighty I have uploaded a (new) simplified version of the file. Your render should look just like mine now. (I'm using Blender 3.2, so make sure you've got that too.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137447/discussion-between-tmighty-and-samuel-sullins).