# How do I match my render to this background?

Tags: hdri

I am trying to copy an animated video. It can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBkMEcBUaEs).

[image: wireframe with background mesh]

I have not found a way to perfectly replicate the same background color.
As it looks to me, the original authors may have used a curved mesh.

That is what I tried to do, too:

[image: wireframe with background mesh]

However, it still does not look right. The device lacks highlights, I think.
I am not sure what I have to change to make it look right.
I am also not even sure if the curved mesh is the right way to go.

Edit:
I am using a gradient material on the background mesh, but it still does not look like in the original video, and I don't manage to get it right.
Here is my [current version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b7W6ZOGTN1ezpafsKr_DPqhE7HUmW8GK/view?usp=sharing).

[image]
[image]

But I do not use a linear gradient as you suggested.
If one darkens the original video image, one can see that the background color is a spherical gradient:

[image]

Comment: Well, you asked this answer yourself before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I achieve this realistic look?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267926/how-do-i-achieve-this-realistic-look)

Comment: @YousufChaudhry No, the question you mentioned does not have such a background.

Comment: *"I am trying to copy an animated video. It can be found here."* - um, where is *here*? There is no link. And why do you use white color for the floor if you want to match the reference image which has a grey-colored floor?

Comment: @Blunder I have added the link, sorry. I am totally unsure how the original video was created, and I don't really see a grey floor in the original video.

Comment: @tmighty No, there is no floor, just an invisible plane used as shadow catcher. However, why don't you just look at the comparison image you put in your question? It's definitely clear that Blunder meant that the lower part of your background is plain white where the original is a medium grey (compare to the white of this page).

Answer (score 3):

### Try making a gradient material for your background mesh:

Use the *Position* from a *Geometry* node.

[image: gradient material]

Adjust the *ColorRamp* to get the colors you want.

Comment: I have tried that already, and the floor was just dark.

Comment: Try using some lighter colors? And/or a brighter light?

Comment: @tmighty So, you want us to find the perfect colors for you, for the gradient to match the original background or what is your goal?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I am still working on it and will report back when I am stuck with a specific problem.

Comment: @tmighty If the answer solved your problem, kindly accept it.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I am still working on it. I don't know yet it if it resoves my background. I will surely report back.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I have updated my question with my latest attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add a gradient node connected to a colour ramp and set the gradient type to *Spherical*:

[image]

Here, you first have to UV Unwrap your background object by seaming all the edges except the middle edge(s) where the top and bottom connect. Then you can just play with the Mapping Node and the Colour Ramp.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a new screenshot to my post. In the original video, the camera rotates around the device, and while that happens (in my opinion) the spherical gradient does not change. Does your suggestion still fit in this scenario?